# cmake installation from bin file

Tags: cmake

I ran a `cmake-3.17.0-rc2-Linux-x86_64.sh`script on Linux and now have a `cmake-3.17.0-rc2-Linux-x86_64` folder with the folders `bin man doc share`. From here, how do I install cmake? When I type cmake, I get `bash: cmake: command not found...`

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

Unless an executable file is in the path, it won't be found unless you provide the fully qualified name. Run `./cmake` instead.